# Kafka Streams Hopping window top N by dimension

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka stream, and I need a processor which does the following:

Uses a 45 second hopping window with 5 second advances to compute the top 5 count based on one dimension of the domain object. For example, if the stream would contain Clickstream data, I would need the top 5 urls viewed by domain name, but also windowed in a hopping window.

I've seen examples to do window counting, for example:

```
KStream<String, GenericRecord> pageViews = ...;

// Count page views per window, per user, with hopping windows of size 5 minutes that advance every 1 minute
KTable<Windowed<String>, Long> windowedPageViewCounts = pageViews
    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), genericAvroSerde))
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5).advanceBy(Duration.ofMinutes(1))))
    .count()
```

And Top n aggregations on the MusicExample, for example:

```
songPlayCounts.groupBy((song, plays) ->
            KeyValue.pair(TOP_FIVE_KEY,
                new SongPlayCount(song.getId(), plays)),
        Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), songPlayCountSerde))
        .aggregate(TopFiveSongs::new,
            (aggKey, value, aggregate) -> {
              aggregate.add(value);
              return aggregate;
            },
            (aggKey, value, aggregate) -> {
              aggregate.remove(value);
              return aggregate;
            },
            Materialized.<String, TopFiveSongs, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(TOP_FIVE_SONGS_STORE)
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(topFiveSerde)
        );
```

I just can't seem to be able to combine the 2 - where I get both windowing and top n aggregations. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In general yes, however, for non-windowed top-N aggregation the algorithm will *always* be an approximation (it's not possible to get an exact result, because one would need to buffer *everything* what is not possible for unbounded input). However, for a hopping window, you would do an exact computation.

For the windowed case case, the actual aggregation step, could just accumulate all input records per window (eg, return a `List<V>` or some other collection). On this result `KTable` you apply a `mapValues()` function that get the `List<V>` of input records per window (and key), and can compute the actual top-N result you are looking for.